# Updating committed file on git to have chmod 700 permissions

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have a committed file on git that currently has permissions 755, but I need it to only have 700. I was wondering if anybody has had experience with this? I was hoping a git bash command existed to simply let me say the exact permissions, but it doesn't seem as so.

What is a bit bothersome as well is I have this file as 700 on my local directory, but it has become 755 when it went onto our Azure DevOps git repo.

Comment: What I mean is the file originally, before comitting, was chmod to 700. After comitting to our git repo on ADS, it changed to 755. I believe this is because of some of the git auto permission stuff, I don't really know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git only stores two types of permissions for plain files: 644 and 755.  That is, it cares only about the executable bit.  There is no way to force a specific set of permissions other than those two types.

If you want the file to have different permissions in the working tree, you can set `core.sharedRepository` to `0600`, which will make files have either 0600 or 0700 permissions, or you can fix it up after the fact with a `post-checkout` hook or a script.  However, none of these are automatic, since Git does not allow pushing configuration or hooks to users, so each user will have to set this appropriately.

Comment: When you say a `post-checkout` hook or script, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: I will also investigate the `core.sharedRepository` method you mentioned. Hopefully one of these methods work.

Comment: See `git help githooks` for information on the `post-checkout` hook.  You could use such a hook to change the permissions of the file in the working tree after checkout, or you could use a different script (e.g., a per-project setup script) to change the permissions.